# Test doesn't remove generated files using factory_boy in django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm using factory_boy to generate arbitrary data to run tests. but after each test it doesn't delete files automatically. Is there anything I should add?

*Any suggestion is highly appreciated*

**Model for test**

```
class TrackFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = "tracks.Track"

    id = factory.Faker("uuid4")
    filename = "Track 01 - track"
    created_by = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    file = factory.django.FileField(filename="test.mp3")
    track_length = 145

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = cls.build(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**Test**

```
class TestViewDeleteTrack(AuthorizedApiTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.url = reverse(list-track)
        self.user_data = UserFactory()
        self.data = TrackFactory(created_by=self.user_data)
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user_data)

    def test_list_tracks(self):
        self.get_and_assert_equal_status_code(status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def test_delete_track_valid_pk(self):
        self.delete_and_assert_equal_status_code(
            "delete-track",
            self.data.pk,
            status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT,
        )
```

**custom methods for testing used above**

```
def get_and_assert_equal_status_code(self, status_code):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status_code)
        return response

def delete_and_assert_equal_status_code(self, url_name, pk, status_code):
        url = reverse(url_name, kwargs={"pk": pk})
        response = self.client.delete(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status_code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Files arent deleted, just the database field that points to the file, you can remove them in your teardown method.

```
import shutil


class MyTest(AuthorizedApiTestCase):
   ...

   def tearDown(self):
        # modify to actually delete what you want to delete.
        shutil.rmtree(settings.UPLOAD_FOLDER)
```

there is also a `tearDownClass` which is the reverse of the `setUpClass`

Comment: I tried it and it says "Access is Denied"

Comment: is there a way to give it permission inside the ```tearDown```